Does using Buffer tank with air water heat pump require 2 water pumps?
Do I need to add second water pump to the radiator side of the buffer tank like this?

I think what is now happening and it makes sense to me is that currently there is nothing pushing water to the floors and it just cycles between buffer and the heatpump.

But is that the case? I do not really understand how the buffer tank works maybe it should somehow work with just one pump?

Yes, you do need a pump for your load side.
The buffer tank is there to prevent short cycling of the heating/cooling source (boiler, chiller, or heat pump). It allows its pump to cycle as it needs it. The load side needs its own pump that will cycle when it needs it. These two sides run independently.

